# Want to close an activity which started from share intent of another app when my app is closed. Right now it is going into backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

1. My app is in closed state.
2. And from share button of another app I am getting content(URL/Image) in my App with share intent.
3. Share activity is opening and after taking some info user is pressing back button(onbackpress).
4. Then I am executing the following code to end the activity, but instead of closing the activity it is showing in App background area(moving in pause mode) with App logo.

   public void onBackPressed() {

   ```
       super.finish();
   ```

   }

**Here is the Manifest file**

```
<activity
        android:name=".xxx"
        android:icon="@drawable/xshareicon"
        android:label="@string/xxxapp"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unable to fully understand your question, but try the below code to see if it helps you:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Question editing please check if it helps. The code you mentioned didn't worked. Thanks

Comment: @ronns please clarify what do you mean by `App background area` - recent apps window like this http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-A8Qse7FSM9k/VW3FGANd6TI/AAAAAAAABns/YZZBqICuJ7A/s1600/Recent-apps-ZenUI_2.png ?

Comment: exactly. though the app is closed the activity I opened via share intent of another app. after backpress the activity is going in that recent apps area instead of fully closing.

Comment: @ronns This is the normal Android behavior. You can see it for yourself:- for example, open the Google `Photos` app and share some random photo on `WhastApp` with your friend...when photo is shared, press back button and you will be back in `Photos` app..again press back button and you will be on your Home screen. Now, if you look into the `Recent Apps` screen you will see both the apps there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `finishAffinity();` to finishActivity Completely  instead `finish();`

Comment: Sorry didn't worked :( still the app logo is showing in recent apps area and also tapping it is not opening my app(it can also resolve this problem).